# How to create a setup or exe in c# winforms that runs only once in lifetime?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

Im creating an windows forms  application in c#  and i want to give its exe or setup to my customers, but my requirement is that after he installing the setup file or exe, he should not be able to use that setup again even in the same system?

How can i restrict him?

Comment: This is the most original approach to licensing problems I have ever heard of

Comment: what if he needs to reinstall it?

Comment: You'd have to have some external service (e.g. web) to monitor a unique key.  There's no way to ensure something on a local system is not removed (e.g. they format their hard drive and re-install).  I'd question such a requirement simply because it only adds friction to users due to its easy of circumvention.

Comment: It would really help if you told us what is motivating this question. Are you trying to prevent different users on the same machine from installing your app? Different machines? You want to force an installation to do ... something?

Comment: @PhilHdt if he needs to reinstall, he needs to contact me for a new setup..

Comment: @DourHighArch the thing is i want to give the setup only for a week and for trial, so  he should not be able to install it on any other system or even in his system again, and if the setup expires after 1 week he should not be able to install it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a unique key embedded in your setup application, or given directly to your customer, like a license key. In order to run the installation, it would have to contact your server over the internet with that key, and your server would validate the key, and then mark it as used, so that if the installation attempts to run again with that license key, your server validation would fail.

Not bullet-proof, but probably good enough for most circumstances.